# multiple file upload (array) php

Tags: php, html, upload

**PHP script**

```
   $count = 0;
    foreach ($_FILES['filesToUpload'] as $file) {
      //upload process
      echo $file[$count]['tmp_name'].',';
      $count ++;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" action="action-here" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input class="btn" name="filesToUpload[]" type="file" multiple="" />
<input class="btn primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I'm doing this majorly wrong. What i'm trying to do is make it so you select the files then  the php script processes it like an array?

I keep getting out puts such as `1,i,C,,,`.

I know other ways to do multiple uploads, but I know this is one of the simplest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach ($_FILES['filesToUpload']['error'] as $k => $error) {
  echo $_FILES['filesToUpload']['tmp_name'][$k].',';
}
```

Tips: debug it with `print_r($_FILES)`.

Comment: I want to make it simple with `$file['tmp_name'][$k]`, but it turns out that the only way is `$_FILES['filesToUpload']['tmp_name'][$k]`.

Answer (score 0):

you should write it [this way](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php):

```
echo $file['tmp_name'][$count].',';
```